# Computing the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, limits

**From Question:**

For each real number x. determine if the sequence $$\left(\frac{1}{{1+x^{n}}}\right)^{\infty}_{n=1}$$ has a limit, and compute it when exist.

**For this answer I'm not sure please advice .**

Let $a_n = \left(\frac{1}{{1+x^{n}}}\right)$

take limit ;           $\lim_{n \to \infty} {a_n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}  {{1+x^{n}}} = 0$

Given $\epsilon > 0$

Hence  $|a_n - 0|$  = $ |$$\frac{1}  {{1+x^{n}}} -0|  =\frac{1}  {{1+x^{n}}}   \leq {\frac{1}  {{n}}} \leq {\frac{1}  {{N}}} < \epsilon$

Choose $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$

$|a_n - L|$  = $ |\frac{1}  {{1+x^{n}}}-0|  =\frac{1}{{1+x^{n}}}   <{\frac{1}  {{n}}} <{\frac{1}  {{N}}}   = {\epsilon}$

=$|\frac{1}{{1+x^{n}}}|<{\epsilon}$, $\forall n \ge N$

it exists when $n \ge\ 1$

Comment: Your proof is a little messy, so I have some questions - are you trying to show that the limit of the sequence is zero for any real number $x$?

Answer (score 1):

For $|x|<1$ we have: 
$$
\lim_nx^n=0 \Longrightarrow \lim_n\frac{1}{1+x^n}=1.
$$
For $|x|>1$ we have
$$
\lim_n|x|^n=\infty \Longrightarrow \lim_n\frac{1}{1+x^n}=0.
$$
For $x=1$ we have
$$
\lim_n\frac{1}{1+x^n}=\frac12.
$$
For $x=-1$ the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

The sequence involves $x^{n}$.

(1)

> Does $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^{n}$ depend on the value of $x$?

(2)

> What happens to $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x^{n}$ when $|x| > 1$? What about $|x| < 1$? $|x| = 1$?

Answer (score 0):

The limit of the sequence depends on the value of $x$. First of all, if $|x|<1$, then $\lim x^n = 0$, thus $\lim a_n = 1$. If $x=1$, then $\lim a_n = 0.5$. If $x>1$, then

$|\frac{1}{1+ x^n}| < \frac{1}{x^n} \to 0$, thus $\lim a_n = 0$. If $x<-1$, then

$|\frac{1}{1+ x^n}| < \frac{1}{|x|^n-1} \to 0$, thus $\lim a_n=0$.